# windows phone app navigation error: NavigationService does not exist in current Context

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a small windows phone application.

I want to navigate from MainPage.xaml to secondPage.xaml

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But it show an error message that NavigateService does not exist in current Context

Comment: Are you working on a Silverlight app or XAML app? `NavigationService` works with Silverlight app.

Comment: I am working on XAML app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on a Windows Phone XAML app, you need to handle navigation using the Frame property of page, like this

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

Also, as you see above, you need to pass `typeof(Page)` instead of `Uri`.

Comment: this.Frame.Navigate(typeof("SecondPage.xaml"))

This is also not working it shows and error "Type Expected"

Comment: It also says type or namespace secondpage.xaml could not be found

Comment: You are passing a string to `typeof()` function. You need to pass the class name. Replace it with `typeof(SecondPage)`, removing .xaml and quotation marks, exactly as I have written in my answer.

Comment: yaa i did try this but its till says that type or namespace could not be found

Comment: Um... have you imported the namespace to which your SecondPage belongs? If you're putting your page in a different folder, by default the page's namespace will have name of that folder. You'll need add a using declaration for that namespace.

Comment: Both the pages belong to same folder and same namespace

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do that in the page constructor?  If you move your code to OnNavigateTo it should be ok....